# about the Central Limit theorem

Tags: probability

The discrete random variable, $X$, has a $Bi(1600,0.1)$ distribution.

(a) Find parameters of a Normal distribution that can be used as an approximation to the distribution of X

(b) Use this Normal distribution to find, approximately $P(X \geq 137)$

I solved the question (a) that the central approximately distribution is $X \sim N(160, 12^2)$. But have problems with question (b), and my solving process is below:$$P(X \geq 137)=P(\frac{X-160}{12} \geq \frac{137-160}{12})$$ $$=P(\frac{X-160}{12} \geq -1.9167)$$ $$=P(X \leq 1.9167)= \phi(1.9167) \approx 0.9724$$

But the answer of (a) is correct, (b) is not. I do not know which part of my calculation comes wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to use a continuity correction so $\dfrac{136.5-160}{12}$ rather than $\dfrac{137-160}{12}$

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you very much!